# issue with fullscreen web layout using css

Tags: html, css

I've got a fullscreen web layout, with two "floating" boxes of text, which are positioned approximately in the middle of the screen. Here is the css for the boxes (they are identical except for vertical orientation on the page):

```
#home-box-1
{
background-image:url('../images/px_trans_brown.png');
margin-top:16%;
margin-left:25%;
width:850px;
height:176px;
}
```

At fullscreen at 1920 x 1080, it looks perfectly fine. The boxes are set to be sized so that they will fit at size minimum (1024 x 768), with room to spare on each side. However when the screen is resized, there is alot of dead space on the left hand side, and the box goes off the screen on the right.

Im no expert at css, but I was under the impression that the "margin-left:25%", would keep a 25% margin from the edge of the screen, no matter what the browser window size.

Anyone have any clue as to how I can fix this?

Comment: Am I misreading it? Are both boxes set to a width of 850px or is that the width of their container?

Comment: There are two boxes (only one is listed above), both @ 850px. So the boxes are containers for content, but there is no container for the boxes outside of the body tag (if that makes sense)

Comment: The `margin-left` is 25% of the width of the parent element, in this case `<body>`. So when `body` is 1024px wide they'll be 256px from the left edge and at 1920px they'll be 480px from the edge. Try setting the left and right margin to `auto` instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will keep the boxes centered, and keep small margin around them.

```
body {
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-right: 75px;
}
#home-box-1 {
  background: #aaa;
  margin-top:16%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width:850px;
  height:176px;
}
```

Comment: Tried that, still doing the same thing :( Lets say you view at 1920x1080 (which is what the designers designed at, unfortunately), fullscreen. Then you take it out of fullscreen, floating browser window. The boxes do reposition themselves, but not as far I feel like they should with a 25% margin. Maybe I'm using the wrong method using margins.... I just want these boxes to stay in the center of the screen, no matter what the size (so long as it never goes smaller than 1024x768)

Comment: Just as a side note, @ 1024x768, there should still be a good 75-100px of space on each side of the boxes, as they are designed. Is there a way to do away with the margins and center them using a different method?

Comment: Okay, that helps quite a bit. If all you want is the boxes to stay centered, change `margin-left` to `margin-left: auto;` and add `margin-right: auto;` and that should do the trick. For the extra space on the sides, try adding `margin-left: 75px; margin-right: 75px` in `body {` or the parent container of your boxes.

Comment: Kyle is correct. To centre the boxes within `body`, set their `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto` and give them a `width`.

Comment: A few other things about the css got screwed up with this, but they are tweakable. This definitely got the desired effect. Thanks!!